Comparing functions with regard to runtime complexity
Just started studying runtime complexity, and I'm starting to compare functions to determine whether one or the other is "faster". I've got five definitions, which can be condensed into three;

Big-O: $f(n) = O(g(n))$, if there exist $c>0$ and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, $\forall n\geq n_0$, $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$
small-o: $f(n) = o(g(n))$, if $\forall c>0$ there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0$, $f(n) <c \cdot g(n)$
$\Theta$: $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, if $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $g(n) = O(f(n))$. That can be translated to; there exist $c_1$, $c_2$ and $n_0$ such that $c_1 \cdot f(n) \leq g(n) \leq c_2 \cdot g(n)$, $\forall n \geq n_0$

So far in the exercises I have solved, I have either come across the second or the third case. For every pair of functions for which I have determined that $f(n) = O(g(n))$, I have also found another c to "bound" $g(n)$.
So my question is (since this can't always be the case), can anyone propose an example of two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $$f(n)=O(g(n))$$ $$f(n)\neq o(g(n))$$ $$g(n) \neq O(f(n))$$

See if you can come up with an example by defining $f$ separately on the odd and even natural numbers (where one part is fast-growing and one part is not).
